# Get width from other element to set to current element but not equals in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a input. I want my div when I append it, it has same width of input. Here my code.

```
$("#search-result").width($("#searchForm").width());
```

But $("#search-result")'width not equals $("#searchForm")'s width. I try to debug it in Chrome inspect element.

[image: jQuery code debug]

But it's gerenate to HTML like this:

[image: HTML code]

Why? Is there any solution to make same width? Thanks

Comment: box-sizing declared as a reset for all would help i believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var searchWidth = $("#searchForm").width() + 'px';
$("#search-result").css('width', searchWidth );
```

Comment: Oh, great! This code make 2 element has same width. But, can you explain me why my code not worked? Thanks.